# Can't use cat to copy from file to another file using execlp in C

Tags: bash, scripts, files, c, copy

I'm using Ubuntu 16.10. I want to copy contents of a file to another file using execlp. I  have two files named file1 (with content) and file2 (empty). If I give the following command on terminal

```
test@ubuntu:~/Teme$ cat file1 > file2
```

Everything works perfect, but if I write a C code and use this:

```
execlp("/bin/cat","cat","file1",">","file2",NULL);
```

I get the error:

```
content of file1
cat: '>': No such file or directory
```

I thought that execlp is taking cat arguments one by one so I tried

```
execlp("/bin/cat","cat","file1 > file2",NULL);
```

but then I got this error:

```
cat: 'file1 > file2': No such file or directory
```

How can I copy the content from a file to another using execlp / execl?

Comment: `cat` does not copy between files -- that's `cp`. `cat` con**cat**enates files to standard output.

Comment: Looks like you are calling `cat` as a command and then as the first parameter to itself: `execlp("/bin/cat","cat","file1 > file2",NULL);`

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix 0th parameter. `$0`/argv[0] is usually the name of the command. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/315812/70524

Comment: @muru Thanks for C clarification, I've only used exec in Conky and from LibreOffice Calc macros which is different.

Answer (score 6):

`> file2` in `cat file1 > file2` are not arguments sent to `cat`. They're interpreted by **the shell** (bash, in this case), to redirect the output of `cat` to `file2`. You can't do this directly via `execlp`. What you're doing is the equivalent of `cat file1 \> file2` in a terminal, where the `>`, being escaped, is not interpreted by the shell.

You need to use [`system()`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/system.3), which uses a shell to execute a command string, or redirect the output using C functions like `open()` and [`dup2()`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com//dup2.2). How to do *that* is a programming question, which belongs on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yep. Or alternatively they can just open file1 for reading and write contents to file2.

Comment: … or you can invoke `cp`, a program that is actually meant to copy files, and use that in your `execlp` invocation: `execlp("cp", "cp", "file1", "file2", NULL);`